# Windows app to grab webcam snapshots?

Tags: windows, webcam, cron, snapshot

I want to periodically capture an image from a webcam attached to a Windows PC, and upload it to a Linux server on the network (preferably FTP, could be SFTP or even Samba).

The images have to be very small; less than 50K.

Any help / ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found a program called webcamimagesave, which seems to do the trick.

Here's the URL: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_cam_image_capture.html

Comment: There's no option to to send images with this one...

Comment: Yes it's (mainly) a movement detector. You may try http://www.yawcam.com/  :)

Answer (score 0):

May be *TeboCam* is what you're looking for.

[TeboCam Web site](http://teboweb.com/WebCam.html)

Comment: That seems to just be a movement detector. I want something that will take a picture every X seconds, and save it somewhere.